# Are orbit polytopes of rotation subgroup of Coxeter group combinatorially equivalent?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, coxeter-groups

Suppose that $G\subset O(d)$ is a finite reflection (finite Coxeter) group. For any $v\in \mathbb{R}^d$ which is not fixed by any non-trivial $g\in G$, one can consider the orbit polytope (Coxeter) permutahedra \begin{equation} P(G;v)=Conv (G\cdot v) \end{equation} given by the orbit.

Now consider $G^+\subset SO(d)$, the index-two rotation subgroup of $G$. Again one can consider the orbit polytope \begin{equation} P(G^+;v)=Conv(G^+\cdot v) \end{equation} for $v$ as above (i.e., not fixed by any non-trivial $g$ from the original group). Is it necessarily the case that $P(G^+;v)$ is just obtained by $P(G;v)$ by "alternation"?

If $v_1,v_2\in \mathbb{R}^d$ are not fixed by any $g\in G$, it can be shown that $P(G;v_1)$ and $P(G;v_2)$ are combinatorially equivalent. Must the same be true for $P(G^+;v_1)$ and $P(G^+;v_2)$ as well?

This would definitely seem to be the case for a number of examples (e.g., for $G=A_2\times A_2\times A_2$, for which $P(G;v)$ is a box, $P(G^+;v)$ is a tetrahedra).

Comment: It depends on what exactly you mean by "alternation". It is the case that $P(G^+;v)$ has exactly half as many vertices as $P(G;v)$. So in this sense $P(G^+;v)$ is obtained from $P(G;v)$ by "skipping every second vertex". Note that $Gv$ is indeed the set of vertices of the polytope $P(G;v)$, because all points in the orbit lie on a sphere, so that none is a convex combination of any others.

Comment: The second question is answered in the positive for the symmetric group in Cruickshank, J., Kelly, S. Rearrangement Inequalities and the Alternahedron.

Comment: @GrantB.'s [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365538/are-orbit-polytopes-of-rotation-subgroup-of-coxeter-group-combinatorially-equiva#comment922857_365538): [Cruickshank and Kelly - Rearrangement inequalities and the alternahedron](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00454-005-1199-6) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2195053)).

Comment: Great; thank you

Comment: My heuristic argument would be the following: the reason that all the $P(G;v)$ have the same combinatorial type is that there is no generic $v$ (i.e. $v$ not fixed by any non-trivial $g$) so that $G\cdot v$ has non-generic affine dependencies (because such must occur when transitioning from one combinatorial type to another).
This obviously translates to no non-generic affine dependencies between the points in $G^+\cdot v$ (since the notion of "generic $v$" stays the same). This can probably be made precise.

Comment: @M.Winter I think it's more subtle than that. The statement is not true for every subgroup of $G$; the answer to the OP's [recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365448/are-cyclic-orbitopes-of-permutahedra-necessarily-simplicies) gives a counterexample for a cyclic subgroup (a "non-generic" affine dependency). The paper I mentioned above discusses the problem of characterizing subgroups with combinatorial orbit polytopes, but to my knowledge not much is known.

Comment: @GrantB. There is certainly something special about $G^+$ that cannot be generalized to other subgroups of $G$. For example, there are no non-generic dependencies as long as $v$ stays in the same Weyl chamber. We know this because there are no non-generic dependencies for $G$. Now, $P(G^+;v)$ has points in exactly half of the Weyl chambers and so we know that for $v$ in any of these we get the same combinatorial type. But putting $v$ in one of the other chambers gives you the mirrored polytope, still combinatorially equivalent to the previous one. Might this already be the subtlety?

Comment: @M.Winter I agree that the problem reduces to showing that the face lattice of $P(G^+;v)$ is independent of $v$ for $v$ in a given Weyl chamber. However this statement is already not true for all subgroups of $G$, as the linked post indicates. The problem is that points in the interior of a Weyl chamber are simply not always generic in the sense of "no extra affine dependencies". There can be and are non-generic affine dependencies in non-degenerate permutahedra, they just aren't among vertices comprising a face of the polytope.

Comment: @GrantB. Oh I got it, I was under the impression that the reflection groups are too nice to have non-generic dependencies inside a Weyl chamber. I was aware of the linked question but have not interpreted the answer in that way. Interesting.

Comment: @M.Winter Yes, I think we are used to polytopes which use a subset of the defining inequalities of permutahedra rather than a subset of vertices, since these tend to be better behaved.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to give a rigorous definition to "by alternation" such that the answer to your first question is "yes".

Given a polytope $P$ whose vertex-edge graph is bipartite, one might say that there are two polytope $Q$ is obtained from $P$ "by alternation" if there is a bipartition of the graph such that $Q$ is the convex hull of one block of the bipartition.

Under this definition, yes, your graph $P(G^+,v)$ is obtained from $P(G,v)$ by alternation.  The requirement that $v$ is not fixed by any (nontrivial) element of $G$ is equivalent to the requirement that $v$ is not fixed by any reflection, or equivalently, not contained in any reflecting hyperplane.  (This is standard...See for example Section 1.12 of Humphreys "Reflection Groups and Coxeter groups".)  The reflecting hyperplanes cut the ambient space into simplicial cones, so we're just choosing $v$ in the interior of one of the cones.  Then the orbit of $v$ contains exactly one point in each of the cones, and this gives a bijection between the orbit and the elements of the group.

The cones define a fan structure on the ambient space (i.e. any two cones intersect each other in faces), and this fan is the normal fan of $P(G,v)$.  If two maximal cones in this fan are adjacent (i.e. share a codimension-1 face), then they are related by a reflection in $G$, so exactly one of the corresponding group elements is in $G^+$.  Thus the vertices of $P(G^+,v)$ are one block of a bipartition of the vertices of $P(G,v)$.

Comment: That's great; thanks. Does it follow that if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not fixed by any (non-identity) $g\in G$, then $P(G^+,v_1)$ and $P(G^+,v_2)$ have to combinatorially equivalent?

Comment: I'm not sure if it follows from the "by alternation" fact, but I suspect it is true.  I also suspect that this is known and that someone has written it down.  But I have not thought carefully about it to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, I should probably put a "reference request" tag on this. I'm pretty certain its true in $\mathbb{R}^3$.